# Второй выпадающий список в ввертикальном меню

Tags: html

Как поправить второй список, чтобы он нормально выпадал?

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.main-menu{
 position: relative;
}

.main-menu .sub-menu{
 position: absolute;
}

.menu_item {
 position: relative;
 width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0 10px;
 background: green;
}
.menu_item a {
 line-height: 35px;
 display: block;
} 
.menu_item:hover {
 color: #000;
 background: #f3f3f3;
}
.menu_item:hover > .sub-menu {
 display: block;
}

.menu_item:hover > .sub-menu-2 {
 display: block;
}

.sub-menu {
 left: 99%;
 margin-top: -32px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 12em;
 display: none;
}
.sub-menu .menu_item {
 width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu-2 {
 left: 120%;
 margin-top: -35px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 12em;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="menu_item">
   <a href="">Menu 1></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li class="menu_item">
      <a href="">Menu 1.1</a></li>
                 <li class= "menu_item">
                  <a href="">Menu 1.2</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="menu_item">
           <a href=""> Menu 1.3 > </a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu-2">
                   <li class= "menu_item ">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.1.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class= "menu_item">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.2.2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class= "menu_item">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.3.3</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class= "menu_item">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.2.4</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class= "menu_item">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.3.5</a>
                   </li>
                  </ul>
                 </li>
             </ul>
     <li class="menu_item">
         <a href="">Menu 2</a>
     </li>
      <li class="menu_item">
         <a href="">Menu 3</a>
     </li>
      <li class="menu_item">
         <a href="">Menu 4</a>
     </li>
      <li class="menu_item">
         <a href="">Menu 5</a>               
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Подойдет?

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
}
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.main-menu{
 position: relative;
}

.main-menu .sub-menu{
 position: absolute;
}

.menu_item {
 position: relative;
 width: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0 10px;
 background: green;
}
.menu_item a {
 line-height: 35px;
 display: block;
} 
.menu_item:hover {
 color: #000;
 background: #f3f3f3;
}
.menu_item:hover > .sub-menu {
 display: block;
}

.menu_item:hover > .sub-menu-2 {
 display: block;
}

.sub-menu {
 left: 99%;
 margin-top: -32px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 12em;
 display: none;
}
.sub-menu .menu_item {
 width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu-2 {
 left: 100%;
 margin-top: -35px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 12em;
 display: none;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="menu_item">
   <a href="">Menu 1></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li class="menu_item">
      <a href="">Menu 1.1</a></li>
                 <li class= "menu_item">
                  <a href="">Menu 1.2</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="menu_item">
           <a href=""> Menu 1.3 > </a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu-2">
                   <li class= "menu_item ">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.1.1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class= "menu_item">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.2.2</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class= "menu_item">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.3.3</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class= "menu_item">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.2.4</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class= "menu_item">
                    <a href="">Menu 1.3.5</a>
                   </li>
                  </ul>
                 </li>
             </ul>
     <li class="menu_item">
         <a href="">Menu 2</a>
     </li>
      <li class="menu_item">
         <a href="">Menu 3</a>
     </li>
      <li class="menu_item">
         <a href="">Menu 4</a>
     </li>
      <li class="menu_item">
         <a href="">Menu 5</a>               
  </li>
 </ul>
```